# Why we have to use API controller instead of controller?

Tags: laravel, api, model-view-controller

I am little bit familiar with the APIController and controller difference. But confused about usage.

The question raised in my mind while I was working with Laravel and AJAX request.

we can do the same work with a simple controller with `Route:: resource();` then why we have to use APIController.

What are the advantages of APIController over controller while working on serialized data transfer through AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Tapan and welcome to SO community :)

Using APIResources is more about clean and well maintained code, as if there is no use of the function or the route why should it be added, one of the reasons; it might confuse the next developer who uses the code.

as per Laravel docs :

> API Resource Routes
>   When declaring resource routes that will be consumed by APIs, ***you will commonly want to exclude routes that present HTML templates such as  create and edit***. For convenience, you may use the apiResource method to automatically exclude these two routes: